# Is it possible to get the number of rows in a CSV file without opening it?

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a CSV file of size ~1 GB, and as my laptop is of basic configuration, I'm not able to open the file in Excel or R. But out of curiosity, I would like to get the number of rows in the file. How am I to do it, if at all I can do it?

Comment: Maybe just `wc -l yourfile.csv` from a command line prompt, or something?

Comment: If the file size is 1 GB you should be able to import it. Of course, you shouldn't do this with `read.table` and friends. Use `fread` from package data.table.

Comment: so you're saying that `nrow(read.csv("file.csv", header= T/F))` crashes R? And yes, `fread` certainly prefered

Comment: @Alex Don't use `read.csv` with a 1 GB file. It's slow.

Comment: If all methods crash, you can use csv splitter to break the big file into chunks.. Not elegant, but might work

Comment: @Roland I don't think it's ideal; but the OP has no reproducibility. Trying to get a baseline

Comment: @Alex If by "not ideal" you mean it can take hours ...

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: [Handling large datasets in R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/handling-large-datasets-in-r/)

Answer (score 68):

For Linux/Unix:

```
wc -l filename
```

For Windows:

```
find /c /v "A String that is extremely unlikely to occur" filename
```

Comment: Regarding the "Windows" solution, note that: (1) this is run from `cmd.exe`; (2) `filename` includes the full path to the file (& turn the slashes around); (3) if there's a header, that 'row' is counted, ie, a file with a header + 10 rows will result in returning `11`. (None of this detracts from the quality of the answer.)

Comment: this does not count the number of rows in a CSV, it counts the number of file lines, which is different. If you have line breaks in the same row, they will be counted separately.

Answer (score 28):

**Option 1:**

Through a file connection, `count.fields()` counts the number of fields per line of the file based on some `sep` value (that we don't care about here).  So if we take the length of that result, theoretically we should end up with the number of lines (and rows) in the file.

```
length(count.fields(filename))
```

If you have a header row, you can skip it with `skip = 1`

```
length(count.fields(filename, skip = 1))
```

There are other arguments that you can adjust for your specific needs, like skipping blank lines.

```
args(count.fields)
# function (file, sep = "", quote = "\"'", skip = 0, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, 
#     comment.char = "#") 
# NULL
```

See `help(count.fields)` for more.

It's not too bad as far as speed goes.  I tested it on one of my baseball files that contains 99846 rows.

```
nrow(data.table::fread("Batting.csv"))
# [1] 99846

system.time({ l <- length(count.fields("Batting.csv", skip = 1)) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.528   0.000   0.503 

l
# [1] 99846
file.info("Batting.csv")$size
# [1] 6153740
```

**(The more efficient) Option 2:**  Another idea is to use `data.table::fread()` to read the first column only, then take the number of rows.  This would be very fast.

```
system.time(nrow(fread("Batting.csv", select = 1L)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.063   0.000   0.063
```

Answer (score 7):

Estimate number of lines based on size of first 1000 lines

```
size1000  <- sum(nchar(readLines(con = "dgrp2.tgeno", n = 1000)))

sizetotal <- file.size("dgrp2.tgeno")
1000 *  sizetotal / size1000
```

This is usually good enough for most purposes - and is a lot faster for huge files.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I used:

```
testcon <- file("xyzfile.csv",open="r")
readsizeof <- 20000
nooflines <- 0
( while((linesread <- length(readLines(testcon,readsizeof))) > 0 ) 
nooflines <- nooflines+linesread )
close(testcon)
nooflines
```

Check out this post for more:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/easy-way-of-determining-number-of-linesrecords-in-a-given-large-file-using-r/

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Tony's answer in R:

```
file <- "/path/to/file"
cmd <- paste("wc -l <", file)
as.numeric(system(cmd, intern = TRUE))
```

This is about 4x faster than `data.table` for a file with 100k lines

```
>     microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+         nrow(fread("~/Desktop/cmx_bool.csv", select = 1L)),
+         as.numeric(system("wc -l <~/Desktop/cmx_bool.csv", intern = TRUE))
+     )
Unit: milliseconds
                                                               expr       min        lq
                 nrow(fread("~/Desktop/cmx_bool.csv", select = 1L)) 128.06701 131.12878
 as.numeric(system("wc -l <~/Desktop/cmx_bool.csv", intern = TRUE))  27.70863  28.42997
      mean   median        uq      max neval
 150.43999 135.1366 142.99937 629.4880   100
  34.83877  29.5070  33.32973 270.3104   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file in notepad++ and scroll till the end of file. you will find the number of rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).