# Select only CSV files with more than 9 rows

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, file, for-loop

I have a folder with hundreds of CSV files that I am loading into my R environment, but I only want to select files with more than 9 rows of data. I want each CSV file to be its own data frame for my next analysis steps.

I already have a way to read in each individual CSV using

```
filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$","", list.files(pattern="\\.csv$"))

for(i in filenames){
  assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to only load in CSVs with more than 9 rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, [Some approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913151/is-it-possible-to-get-the-number-of-rows-in-a-csv-file-without-opening-it), wrap it in an if, open if > 9 or don't, or just use the results to build your desired files list.

Comment: Suggestion, do not use `assign()` but instead read each file in and store it as an element in a list.  This will make life easier when it comes time to process each data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from being really fast, package {[vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/vroom.html)} has some nice utilities for dealing with many text files.

Example:

- get file names:

```
all_files <- list.files('path/to/csv/dir', pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
```

- keep only names of files > 9 lines:

```
library(vroom)

large_files <- 
  all_files |>
  Filter(f = \(file_name) length(vroom_lines(file_name)) > 9)
```

- read the large files into a data frame, keeping the source files' paths in column 'source_file' (use this column for groupwise data analysis, e.g. with {dplyr}):

```
all_data <- vroom(large_files, id = 'source_file')
```

- you can create a separate dataframe object per source file like so, if you absolutely must ;-)

```
large_files |>
  Map(f = \(file_name) read.csv(file_name)) |>
  setNames(nm = gsub('.*/(.*)\\..*', '\\1', large_files)) |>
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check nrow first, then only load files that pass. On Linux we can use `wc`. Here an example using more than two rows for sake of brevity. We need to increment by one, `> 2L + 1L`, since header also is counted as row.

```
> setwd('~/sandbox')
> (fls3 <- system('for file in *.csv; do echo "$(wc -l < "$file"),$file"; done', 
+                intern=TRUE) |> 
+   read.csv(text=_, header=FALSE) |> 
+   subset(V1 > 2L + 1L))
  V1         V2
1  4 file01.csv
3  4 file03.csv
> lapply(fls3$V2, read.csv) |> setNames(fls3$V2)
$file01.csv
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12

$file03.csv
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12
```

---

*Data:*

```
## produces 3 .csv files w/ 4, 3, 4 rows and 4 columns
setwd('~/sandbox')
n <-  3
set.seed(42)
lapply(seq_len(n), \(i) {
  o <- if (rnorm(1) > 0) {
    data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
  } else {
    data.frame(matrix(1:8, 2, 4))
  }
  write.csv(o, sprintf('file%02d.csv', i), row.names=FALSE)
})
```